# regex extract in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get this string out of GoogleSheets - basically everything up until the first "\"

So here's the full cell: name:8MrFF0jIZ30efAY9043guuaEh2QvFdeeVVQDslvTAXUtxyIdLEMOZ9ehUEhuvwti4guIAHN2yRb7mAcPdrnijM_BxK98-fVPXjaZyCWR9GXa8KC4SauB2uRdsdVKk-qiemw\u003d\u003d

And the desired string:
8MrFF0jIZ30efAY9043guuaEh2QvFdeeVVQDslvTAXUtxyIdLEMOZ9ehUEhuvwti4guIAHN2yRb7mAcPdrnijM_BxK98-fVPXjaZyCWR9GXa8KC4SauB2uRdsdVKk-qiemw

Currently, I am doing this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"name:(.*""\"")")
```

but this is not working

Comment: Please provide more samples so we can see a pattern and provide a solution not only specific for this one. Would be better if you can provide a sample sheet with your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=regexextract(A2,"name:([^\\]*)")
```

[image]